# Does indexing make selecting all rows (one cloumn) faster?

Tags: android, sqlite, indexing, android-room

I know that creating an index on a column makes retrieving data from it by specifying a where clause faster. But does it also make retrieving all data in such column (about a million rows) faster?

Edit: my question is about selecting a single column from all rows e.g.

```
SELECT column FROM table
```

Which returns the column data from all rows

Comment: See https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx (and the rest of that page)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

SELECT field is faster than select *.

Because if you have more than 1 field/column in your table then select * will return all of those, and that requires network bandwidth and more work for the database to fetch all the other fields. But if you only require one field/column, the database load is less and it doesnt need to transmit unneeded information and thus take bandwidth resources uncesseraly.

Comment: ???????? What has this to do with an index? On one column! All rows. Not all fields.